# How do I get amixer PCM numid=3 to work on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with speakers connected to the 3.5mm jack. I have no HDMI connected, but I have the standard 7 inch monitor connected. It runs raspbian.

**Edit:** I found out that this was normal behaviour due to an OS update, se my comment below.

If I run `amixer cset numid=3 1` I get the error `amixer: Cannot find the given element from control default`.

If I run `amixer contents` there are no numid=3, I only get:

```
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=-10239,max=400,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-102.39dB,step=0.01dB,mute=1
```

So PCM playback route with numid=3 is missing, and 1+2 say Headphone instead of PCM, that is the normal as far as I can tell from the interweb.

I can still play things with aplay and omxplayer (I'm not sure if it is mono or stereo).

But some other things fails, which I thought might be because of this. If I run espeak, and similar with pyttsx3 in python, I get screens full of errors, a few of the lines are:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

And that is what I actually would want to get to work.
If that is caused by the first error I don't know. But when I search for rPi sound problems, the cset-numid=3 "solution" seems to appear everywhere, and I can't use that...

**Edit:** So that turns out not to be the reason, the espeak problem is still there even if I revert to the old way with options in boot.txt.

Comment: Ok, so I found out why PCM is missing and numid=3 don't work, that is caused by a recent upgrade to raspbian, described here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/latest-raspberry-pi-os-update-may-2020/
https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/26628/audio-issues-after-latest-raspbian-updates/2

Using the boot-options to go back to the old module fixed some programs that had problem picking the right mixer by name, but espeak still will not work. That probably should be another question though.

Answer (score 3):

I needed three days to find out how to use it on Raspberry Pi. I created an Shell Command. When you want to use Audio via 3.5mm Jack just write. You can let the HDMI Cable connected.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e " defaults.pcm.card 1 \ndefaults.ctl.card 1" > /etc/asound.conf'
```

if you want to use the HDMI Audio output just change the number 1 to 0.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e " defaults.pcm.card 0 \ndefaults.ctl.card 0" > /etc/asound.conf'
```